# How to apply localization in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

Is there default way to apply localization packet globaly to all Application from `/extjs/locale/` in ExtJS 4.1 MVC?

Maybe some `Ext.Application` or `Ext.Loader` metods/properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so.
You have to load the appropriate file in extjs/locale/

For example(tomcat server), 
in index.jsp
You can do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/locale/ext-lang-<%=language %>.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've loaded locale file but it has no effect.

Comment: Load it after load bootstrap.js

Comment: I did, but for example my `LoadMask` remains engish. Should I use specific Classes in `extends` property of my loaded classes?

Comment: ypan's answer is correct. Standard ExtJs components should be localized when including the proper locale file before application startup. Don't you see any localized texts, e.g. when loading a Ext.MessageBox or a date form field? 
You will have to provide more information on what you are doing => show us some code!

Comment: Loadmask's default msg is not localized I think.So what you can do is to use new Ext.LoadMask(myPanel, {msg:'<spring:message code="Loading" />'}); if you use java enviroment, and localize the key "Loading".

Comment: @mistaecko I did how ypan said, loaded locale file afer bootstrap, but still have english LoadingMask message. I've inspected my locale file and found LoadMaksk redefining to my langage, but it doesn't work. See my updated question please.

Comment: Thanks in advance, guys. I've managed that my Application is really localized. I wasn't using widgets (like `datefield`) to check my application is localized or not. I've sed `datefield` just for test, and it was localized ok! But I have the problem about my LoaderMask localization but it would be my next question.

Comment: this can't be the solution...it implies the use of server-side code (JSP in this case) and extjs it's a full client framework

Answer (score 1):

(You can also load locale file dynamically via JS)

To localizate Built-in Ext JS component, add the following code your `app.js`:

    `launch: function() {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = "extjs/locale/ext-lang-" + navigator.language; 
        head.appendChild(script);
    }`

To localizate custom Ext JS component, use [Locale.js](https://github.com/cwtuan/Locale.js/).
We have used it in two Ext JS projects. Pretty simple.

Comment: In addition to this, if we want the ext lang message to come in the non US locale then : get the current locale and pass it in url as -> script.src = "extjs/locale/ext-lang-" + localeLang; This will allow ext js to load the ext default messages such as min/max text message loaded in the user's locale.